# How to make a webpage link load without reloading the whole webpage

Tags: html, reload

Sorry for the confusing title, I could not think of how to describe it in words. With this being said, I'll try to show you what I mean. If you go to www.icracked.com/repair you can click the device, and it'll load the next set of options without reloading the whole webpage. I want to do the same thing, but I can't figure out how to, so if anyone can point me to the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Short answer: JavaScript.  Long answer: would take a book.

Answer (score 1):

Are you simply trying to show a user multiple bits of information, as they click on different parts of the web page? Or do you need to gather and manipulate the user input, and do something with it later? (For instance, user clicks on 'iPhone', then clicks on '4S', and now you want to write code to execute based on their choice.)

If the first scenario is what you want, consider using CSS to create some hidden DIVS. These can be triggered by certain events such as click or mouseover.

Without knowing a bit more detail about what you are trying to do, it may not be possible for me to answer as clearly as you would like.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think its the first scenario. All I want to do is let a customer quickly click on the device they have, and the repair they need repaired without having it constantly reload a new webpage. When it gets to the last step of the selection process, it then redirects them to the page of the selected device and selected repair.